# Birthday calculation results in nothing

Tags: php, datetime

This is how I started making a birthday system to say how old you are, like on Facebook. So now I'm doing it in Danish 11-1-1993. This is the first day and after months and here after years of when to come into the world or what to say.

Here I show you some code on how I chose to do it, but the problem is such that it does not bother to show up in some way it's just empty.

```
<li>Alder: <?php echo $alder_d;?>/<?php echo $alder_m;?>-<?php echo $alder_aar;?> - 
                            <?php
                            $alle_alder = $alder_d . $alder_m . $alder_aar;
                            function age_from_dob($alle_alder) {
                                return floor((time() - strtotime($alle_alder)) / 31556926);
                            }
                            ?>
                            </li>
```

Asks if you want to know more

It's down here in function as I'd like it to find out how old you are.

Comment: You havent called your age_from_dob function - so I wouldnt expect it to print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate years you can just

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("now");
$datetime2 =  DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", "11-1-1993");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%y Years');
```

Output

```
18 Years
```

Comment: It comes up with an error:( I have made code like this so that the called $ alle_alder the months and days and years

Comment: error are ; Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (1111993) at position 4 (9): Unexpected character' in /home/appsdanm/public_html/profil.php:89 Stack trace: #0 /home/appsdanm/public_html/profil.php(89): DateTime->__construct('1111993') #1 {main} thrown in /home/appsdanm/public_html/profil.php on line 89

Comment: What version of PHP are you using and what did you edit in the code .. see live demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/6mSBKg

Comment: $ alle_alder it is coming from the database.

Comment: i have try its her: [link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/50K8YK)

Comment: `var_dump($alle_alder)` and put the output here

Comment: @Jesper Petersen see updated code : http://codepad.viper-7.com/Bv5khD

Comment: alright thanks. but that is how the profile page so it just download profile months and days and years down. I think just if another user creates a user and his birthday 11-1-1990 only may be he have it, the database should just even find out if you can follow me

Comment: I would like to give you approved or what they say ..